# can't update spree product price with non admin role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm creating a Store Manger role and i want to give him access to create and update products, now I'm able to create products & modify everything except price, I've tried the below but no success

```
can %i[update modify], Spree::Price
```

any idea how can i give my new role access to update product price ?

Comment: Spree use cancancan to set permissions https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/ability.rb. [here](https://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/security.html) is a good example of how to add more ability to spree

Comment: already did that, the missing one is only adding the ability to update prices & i have tried the above but didn't work